# ssh login attempts and commands history between server A to server B in centos

Tags: linux, centos, ssh

is there a way to know :

1 - how i can see all the commands history ( i know that the commands are stored in bash-history but if the ssh connection was made between two servers 'server A to server B' the commands from server A are not stored)

2- how i can see all the login attempts between two servers (i know the command "last" and "lastb" but it doesn't show the login attempts between two servers 'server A to server B' )

Comment: I don't understand part (1): If you connect from A to B, then there is just one set of commands which is stored in the history on B (unless the connection breaks and prevents a clean shutdown of the shell. (2) The login attempts are logged in `/var/log/auth.log`; depending on the SSH log level.

Comment: hi, thank you for the reply, i don't have this file auth.log i have centos 6

Comment: In Centos the file seems to be located in `/var/log/secure`.